# How to assign various commands to a mouse button, time dependent in xbindkeys?

Tags: linux, mouse, xbindkeys

I need to execute differents commands respect at the time I keep pressed a mouse key.

I was looking for an alternative to XMBC in linux, I'm using xbindkeys from a time to now but what I miss from my old config is executing various commands assigned to a button respect to different delays each one.
I found the scripts in [xbindkeys doubleclick](https://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html#utilities) useful but those don't acomplish my goal.
My choices then were working with bash or with guile I go with bash I left my answer below.

More answers are welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer, I uploaded to a [repo](https://github.com/lmtapia/hold_n_release_multicommand) but its a small script that takes differences between the press time and the release time here is it. there is room for improvements I noticed just now but it's bedtime, well let me now if its useful to anyone.

```
#!/bin/bash
# hold_n_release.sh

BASE="`dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")"`"
BUTTON=$1
DELAY=$2
PROGS=$BASE/hold_n_release.$BUTTON.commands
LOCK=$BASE/tmp/hold_n_release.$BUTTON.lock
LINES=$(wc -l < $PROGS)

if [ -z "$BUTTON" -o -z "$DELAY" -o ! -f $PROGS ]; then
  echo "Usage : hold_n_release <Button> <Delay (sec)> [release]"
  echo "put the commands on a file named $BASE/hold_n_release.<Button>.commands one per line" 
  exit
fi
EPOCH=$(date +'%s')

if [[ "$3" == "release" &&  -e $LOCK ]] ; then
  LASTTIME=`cat $LOCK`
  CHOICE=$(( (EPOCH - LASTTIME) / DELAY + 1 )) 
  # echo $CHOICE
  if [ $CHOICE -le $LINES ]; then
    exec $(sed  -n "$CHOICE{p;q}" $PROGS) &
  fi
else 
  rm -f $LOCK
  echo  "$EPOCH" > $LOCK; 
fi
```

It needs a file with the commands each one in a line like in the example below, the last line it's intended.

```
xdotool ctr+c
copyq menu
```

Then simple using in xbindkeysrc in the following form

```
#Multicommand hold
"hold_n_release.sh 8 1"
  b:8
#Multicommand release
"hold_n_release.sh 8 1 release"
  b:8 + Release
```

Edit: Github username